# angular2: Extracting data from params

Tags: angular

I am trying to use params in angular2 based on [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html), but i have some problems

1-The Route is:

```
{ path:'single-picture/:comment', component:SinglePictureComponent  },
```

comment is an object which keeps some data:

```
   comments:{
        data:data[];
    } ;
interface data{
            text:string;
            from:from;    
}
```

2- Make a link based on params:

```
    <a  [routerLink]="['/single-picture/:comment', {comment:SomeComments  } ]" >
Some text to show
    </a>
```

3-In the target component,

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router'
export class SinglePictureComponent{


    constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute){

    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.route.params.forEach(params =>
                                console.log(params['data']))
        };
}
```

In the ngOnInit, i tried to have an access to the `comments.data[0].text`, but it seems that my current code does not work!!!
It just prints `undefined`. So how can i find access to data in params?

Comment: Try `console.log(params['comment'])` ?

Comment: it prints **[object%20Object]**